# Using Android PagedList for Charts and Lists

Tags: android, kotlin, paging

I am using Android API Level 28 with android components.

I have an app that displays our data visually in a chart. I'd like to background load the data and begin charting it as it comes in. I also would like you to be able to view the data as a list.

Ideally, the data for the chart and the list would be the same object instances. After all, the network call to retrieve the data is expensive. Plus, depending on the filters selected, there could be a lot of data to be charted.

I cannot use a server-based chart building API; I must draw graphics from the data on the device.

I am able to download the data in the background and build the chart. I looked into PagedList et al for the list view and that works terrifically.

What I cannot figure out is how to share the data. In other words, if you view the chart first then the list, the list should not trigger a download again since the data is already there. Likewise if the user scrolls through the list then looks at the chart.

This is especially helpful for tablets where one side displays the list and the other is the chart (eg, tapping on an item in the list highlights the data point in the chart).

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What I tend to do is to build a class that handles the downloading of the data, then hand it out to whoever wants it
like

```
class BananaProvider {
    private var _bananaData: List<String>? = null
    val bananas: List<String>
        get() {
            _bananaData?.let{ return _bananaData!!}
            _bananaData = getBananaData()
            return _bananaData!!
        }
    fun getBananaData(){
        (...)        
    }
}
```

and perhaps have a function for refilling your babana's with fresh data if you want.

Then, just drop an instance of the BananaProvider in every fragment/function/whatever that needs it.

Alternatively, if you want to share the data between activities, you could serialize it and send it in an intent, or drop it in an SQLite database if you want to save it locally for later use.

Comment: I want to take advantage of PagedList and friends. The scrolling is significantly faster. It can bring down a 3,000 element list as fast as you can scroll through it (providing you have a decent WiFi connection). I've got something which I will write up shortly and post here.

Answer (score 0):

What I wound up doing was:

- Created a DataSource with the functions to fetch the data from the server. I'm using a PositionalDataSource.
- Created a DataSourceFactory to deliver my DataSource
- Created a LiveData using LivePagedListBuilder with my factory and a PagedList.Config (to bring in 100 records at a time, which seems optimal for my needs)

It's the LiveData that I share between the RecyclerView and the chart.

The object which controls the download for the chart keeps track of the current download position and size. If the chart winds up creating the shared LiveData, this will trigger the initial download and populate the underlying PagedList that LiveData is observing.

Each time data comes down, I update the download position and size and draw points for the data just received. If the data isn't complete, I found that I have to wait a few milliseconds before triggering the next download using the PagedList's loadAround function.

If the RecyclerView is the thing which is opened first by the user, its PagedListAdapter automatically brings the data down through the same DataSource and it fills the shared LiveData as the user scrolls.

When I switch back to the Chart, since the LiveData is already populated (all or partially), it can draw the points. If the data isn't complete yet, the PagedList will attempt to load the rest, drawing the points of the data coming down.

It's a pretty neat method. The key was keeping the LiveData around and reusing it and figuring out how to "manually" populate it when not using RecyclerView.